# Spark assembly file uploaded despite spark.yarn.conf being set

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I submit jobs to a Spark cluster running on Yarn using spark-submit sometimes through a relatively slow connection. In order to avoid uploading the 156MB spark-assembly file for each job, I set the configuration option `spark.yarn.jar` to the file on HDFS. However, this does not avoid the upload, but rather takes the assembly file from the HDFS Spark directory and copies it to the application directory:

```
$:~/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6$ bin/spark-submit --class MyClass --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://node-00b/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar my.jar
[...]    
15/07/06 21:25:43 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource hdfs://node-00b/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar -> hdfs://nameservice1/user/XXX/.sparkStaging/application_1434986503384_0477/spark-assembly.jar
```

I was expecting that the assembly file should be copied within the HDFS, but actually it seems to be downloaded and uploaded again which is quite counter-productive. Any hints on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both HDFS have to be the same system. See relevant codes here:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/37bf76a2de2143ec6348a3d43b782227849520cc/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L1308

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L1308

Any reason why you can't have spark assembly jar on nameservice1 HDFS instead?